# The most common letter in a string (Python)

Tags: python, string

I have an exercise to find the most common letter in a string, excluding punctuation symbols, digits and whitespaces and the result should be in lowercase "A"== "a".

What I have:

```
import string
def most_common_letter(text: str):
    s = string.ascii_lowercase 
    text = text.lower()
    counter = {}
    for i in text:
        if i in s:
            counter[i] = 1
        for k,v in counter.items():
            if k == i:
                v += 1
    return counter
```

But in result my dictionary doesn't count. Where is mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You're never incrementing the counts in `counter`. You just set the count to `1` whenever the character is in `s`. The loop that increments `v` has no effect on the dictionary.

You can use `defaultdict(int)` to create a dictionary that automatically initializes elements to `0` the first time you access them.

After filling in the dictionary, you can get the maximum count, and then find all the letters with that count.

```
import string
from collections import default dict

def most_common_letter(text: str):
    s = string.ascii_lowercase 
    text = text.lower()
    counter = defaultdict(int)
    for i in text:
        if i in s:
            counter[i] += 1
    highest = max(counter.values())
    return [k for k, v in counter.items() if v == highest]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

def most_common_letter(text: str):
    counter = {}
    for letter in text.lower():
        if letter not in counter:
            counter[letter] = 0
        if letter in ascii_lowercase:
            counter[letter] += 1
    return max(counter, key=counter.get)
```

This solution increments the value after making sure that the key exists in the dictionary, and then returns the key with the max value.

Answer (score -1):

First lowercase string

```py
s = "Ascsdfavsdfsdassdf!@5DFA7&".lower()
```

Next, keep only alphabetic characters

```py
s_alpha = filter(lambda x:x.isalpha(), s)
```

finally, use `Counter` to count repeated characters and keep the most common ones.

```py
from collections import Counter
most_char = Counter(s_alpha).most_common(1)
print(most_char)
# output: [('s', 6)]
```

**Note:** `most_char[0][0]` printed char

you can read all lines in a function and run it

```py
def most_common_letter(text: str) -> str:
    text_lowercase: str = text.lower()
    text_alpha: str = filter(lambda x:x.isalpha(), text_lowercase)
    most_char: List[tuple] = Counter(text_alpha).most_common(1)
    return most_char[0][0]
```